# Crystal Reports - selecting records that don't match criteria

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I'm sure that this should be easy but I'm really struggling with a record selection formula.

I have inherited a report that uses the following formula to select records:

```
{LU_LEA_DCSF.LEA_DCSF_Description} = {?LEA} and
{DT_YP_SEPTEMBER_GUARANTEE.Created} > DateTime (2014, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00) and
{DT_YP_TRACKER.Academic_Year} = "2014" and
{DT_YP_TRACKER.Tracker_Type_Code} = "2"
```

This checks for a guarantee record from this year and then checks for the correct type of guarantee and it works fine.

However; my line manager would now like to create a list of all those people who **don't** have a guarantee. The problem is that they may have had a guarantee entered last year which means that you can't do a 'null' check (I think).

I hope this makes sense,
Alan

UPDATE with further examples:
There is a DT_YP table which has a record for each young person we work with and there is a YP_Ref in the DT_YP_SEPTEMBER_GUARANTEE table so it is entirely possible for each YP to have none, one, two or more links to the GUARANTEE table and I need to find if they don't have a link or they don't have a current link (ie. after 1/1/14)

Comment: What field in database will give you whether people have gurantee or not?

Comment: @Siva, It's whether there is a record in the DT_YP_SEPTEMBER_GUARANTEE table - but they might have had one from last year so i guess it's kind of: there is not a record or a record from before 1/1/14

Comment: You can add the `NOT` keyword to reverse a Boolean condition, such as `AND NOT {TD_YP_SEPTEMBER_GUARANTEE.CREATED} > ...` this can filter for only records without that (though if there is no record in that table to start with, you might have to add in `NULL` logic or fiddle with `LEFT JOIN`s).

Comment: @AHiggins; I think that's where I was getting stuck. I had tried a simple `NOT` around the entire formula but that didn't work. Also, as you say, if there is no record that I would have no idea how to check for that. :o(

Comment: One query here if people have no gurantee then no record then how can you get count?

Comment: Will there be any yes or no flags for gurantee along witj date

Comment: @Siva; no there is no yes/no flag. Just a link to the person in the DT_YP_SEPTEMBER_GUARANTEE table. ie. YP_Ref in both tables refers to a person so every record for a person in the YP table either has a link to the guarantee table or not but if they do then it could be an old link from last year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your criteria seems to be:

> Select all records that do not have a match in the
>   DT_YP_SEPTEMBER_GUARANTEE table with a Created date in this year.

Based on that, I would do the following:

1) Change your JOIN condition to DT_YP_SEPTEMBER_GUARANTEE to be a

```
LEFT JOIN DT_YP_SEPTEMBER_GUARANTEE
ON *whatever the current condition is*
AND {DT_YP_SEPTEMBER_GUARANTEE.Created} > DateTime (2014, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00)
```

2) Add a statement to your WHERE clause to the effect of (can't remember if this is the Crystal syntax):

```
{DT_YP_SEPTEMBER_GUARANTEE.YP_Ref} IS NULL
```

This will try to establish a link between your existing tables and the September table based on both the fact that the keys match AND that the September table's record are from this year, and make sure that no people who meet that criteria are included in the result set.